# how to save variables in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I am debugging a C++ program, there is variable named *image*, which is a 2D array, each element in it corresponds to a pixel. How can I save this variable so that I can analyze it in Matlab?

The only way I can think of is, insert a snippet in the source code, which opens a file using fopen() and write data into it. But this is could be tedious, since I have a lot of image varibles needs to be exported and I have insert snippet everywhere.

＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝Edit＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝
Copy in the Auto window then paste won't work. It gives me something like this

```
-       m_alMask    0x14da1389  char [512][1024]
+       [0] 0x14da1389 ""   char [1024]
+       [1] 0x14da1789 ""   char [1024]
+       [2] 0x14da1b89 ""   char [1024]
+       [3] 0x14da1f89 ""   char [1024]
```

I am using Visual Studio 2008. Is this version too old so it can not unfold the array? Or the array is too large to be unfolded?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Matlab's parsing capabilities, but on the Visual Studio side, having this code, for example:

```
int a[3][3] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
```

you can right-click on that variable in either `Autos`, `Locals` or `Watch` window and select `Copy Value`. This will copy a text like this:

```
0x0090fc94 {0x0090fc94 {0, 1, 2}, 0x0090fca0 {3, 4, 5}, 0x0090fcac {6, 7, 8}}
```

that you can paste into anything.

If Matlab can read this and ignore the addresses - you are done.

Comment: I tried this before. It did not work. I added that in original post. If I can paste something like this, matlab can parse it.

Comment: @YannLegrands I no longer have 2008; does it have `Copy Value` (NOT `Copy`) option?

Comment: In the Auto window, it only has Copy. The above result is given by Copy in the Auto window. In the Editor, when I hover over then right click, it did have an option Copy Value, but it would simply copy the address of the array. If I mannually unfold the 2D array (by click the + icon), twice, I can copy a single element. It seems there is no way to copy entire array in VS2008.